# In struts2 framework, DTO consists of list<String>. Its not getting populated from S:select tag

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am new to struts2 and looking at the existing code and elsewhere in the net, I thought my below code should work. I am trying to select some user ids in s:select box in JSP and I want to use these ids in my action class. I am using modelDriven for it and users are in a list

JSP code snippet

```
<s:select id="selectedAgents" 
          name="selectedUserList"
          multiple="true"               
          list="selectedUserList"
 />
```

the selected user ids in the page comes to this box. and when the form is submitted, I expect to see the selectUserList in action.

In the action I have

```
public class WorkLoadReportAction extends GenericAction implements ModelDriven<WorkloadReportDTO> 
...

private WorkloadReportDTO userReportInputData = new WorkloadReportDTO();

...
@Override
    public WorkloadReportDTO getModel() {
        return userReportInputData;
    }
```

the `WorkloadReportDTO` has `List<String> selectedUserList` and its getter and setter.

Now in the method of the action(called from submit), I dont see the `selectedUserList` populated.

What am I missing?

Comment: Default interceptor stack ?

Comment: Could you post a code for a model?

Comment: As I mentioned, I am new to this. I did not understand your question. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @user2353827 I wanted to see `WorkloadReportDTO.java`.

Comment: @RomanC I think he was answering me. OP: are you using the default interceptor stack (your package extends "struts-default" and you have not defined any custom interceptor stack) ?

Comment: In oother words, post `WorkloadReportDTO.java` and `struts.xml`

Comment: @AndreaLigios I don't see to whom OP has answered, if OP didn't mention it in a comment means that to everybody.

Comment: Yeah but it's hard to not understand "post model code", while "default interceptor stack" could be more enigmatic to newbies...

Answer (score 1):

In your Jsp :

```
<s:select id="selectedAgents" 
      name="selectedUserList"
      multiple="true"               
      list="selectedUserList"
```

/>

You have `name attribute` value and `list attribute` value as same . Try changing the value of either `name attribute` or `list attribute` .

Hope this Solves your problem